Transition analysis in a particular Website
I'm looking for a way to determine the animation used in this website, when scrolling and changing the displayed project : https://www.oscarpico.es/
Or could someone tell me the name of the animation or how it's done (pure CSS, WebGL or other way...)?
I tried the animation inspector in Chrome Devtools but it only detects CSS animations.
Thanks in advance!
PS: I'm trying to implement it using NextJS 14

This is not really a good question for this platform, please post a more suiting one next time.

Here is the stack that the website is using.

The smooth library you're looking for is called Lenis.
To find those, I use Wappalyzer.
